# Maven aggregate build's install works but compile fails

Tags: maven

I've 3 maven projects, all of which `mvn compile`/`mvn install` successfully from their respective directories.

The aggregate POM looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>Module1</module>
        <module>Module2</module>
        <module>Module3</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn compile` from parent directory, `Module2` fails to build saying it can't find `Module1` classes. But `mvn compile` inside `Module2` directory works just fine!

Why parent project won't compile ?

**Update** It gets weird: `mvn install` on parent is successful, but `mvn compile` is not !!

Comment: Can you print the exact maven output?

Comment: Where are `Module1`, `Module2`, and `Module3`?  Are they nested inside the project?

Comment: Did you specify that Module2 has a dependency on Module1 in the pom.xml of Module2 ?

Comment: @EricJablow Yes they are sub-directories of parent.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Yes, `Module2` compiles successfully, when I run `mvn compile` from its own directory. It's just the parent POM which gives error.

Comment: Do modules have parent POM defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `mvn install`. It is normal that `mvn compile` does not work. Module2 tries to load the needed classes from your local repository. If you do not do an `install` then the classes are not in your local repository and then Module2 cannot find the Module1 classes.